# SQlite Error: no such table: while using join

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables joined together with third many-to-many relation. I'm trying to do select, but SQLite (version 3.11.0) keep telling me that my one of them doesn't exist which is not true! I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Here are my tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS traits;
CREATE TABLE traits(
     trait_id    INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(trait_id) = 'integer'),
     name        VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(name) = 'text'),
     uri         VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(uri) = 'text'),
     PRIMARY KEY (trait_id)
  );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trait_categories;
CREATE TABLE trait_categories(
     trait_category_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(trait_category_id) = 'integer'),
     efo_id            VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(efo_id) = 'text'),
     name              VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(name) = 'text'),
     uri               VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(uri) = 'text'),
     PRIMARY KEY (trait_category_id)
  );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trait_categories_traits;
CREATE TABLE trait_categories_traits(
     trait_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(trait_category_id) = 'integer'),
     trait_id          INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(TYPEOF(trait_id) = 'integer'),
     FOREIGN KEY (trait_category_id) REFERENCES trait_categories(trait_category_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (trait_id) REFERENCES traits(trait_id)
  );
```

Here is my SELECT which fails:

```
SELECT trait_categories.name, traits.name
FROM trait_categories JOIN trait_categories_traits ON trait_categories_traits.trait_category_id = trait_categories.trait_category_id
                      JOIN traits.trait_id         ON trait_categories_traits.trait_id = traits.trait_id;
```

SQLite say:

```
sqlite> select trait_id from traits limit 1;
663
sqlite>     SELECT trait_categories.name, traits.name
   ...>     FROM trait_categories JOIN trait_categories_traits ON trait_categories_traits.trait_category_id = trait_categories.trait_category_id
   ...>                           JOIN traits.trait_id         ON trait_categories_traits.trait_id = traits.trait_id;
Error: no such table: traits.trait_id
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN joins two tables, so it wants two table names.
But `traits.trait_id` is not a table name.

It appears you wanted to join the `traits` table, so remove the `.trait_id`. (And when both columns have the same name, using USING is simpler.)

```
SELECT ...
FROM trait_categories
JOIN trait_categories_traits USING (trait_category_id)
JOIN traits                  USING (trait_id);
```